# Android Studio Element above another

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I just started "programming" in Android Studio and i can't make 1 element above another one.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.krzysztofbzoma.minutnik.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dwukropek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text=":" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minuta_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/minuta_2"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="0" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minuta_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dwukropek"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="0" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sekunda_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dwukropek" 
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="0" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sekunda_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sekunda_1"
        android:text="0" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I need make 2 button above every "0". One under and one above it like on the picture. It need to have width same as this number and be aligned to it so it won't move if i rotate screen. I tried with another layouts but i don't understand difference between LinearLayouts and RelativeLayouts.

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbMV8.png)

Comment: please give the image for example...

Comment: @Shivam Picture Added

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.krzysztofbzoma.minutnik.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minuta_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minuta_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dwukropek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sekunda_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sekunda_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sry but no. Now it's looking like this : http://i.imgur.com/4SA6T4h.png So it's almost same.

Comment: So how you want it to look like..!!